# Gutenberg - Call google map render function in save after DOM has been rendered

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I have a bit of a dilemma.

In the save function I need to call a function renderMap that renders a dynamic google map. However I need to call it after the DOM has been rendered. I can't seem to find a solution for this. I realised you can't add a class to the save function with the React lifecycle so I am stopped. It does work for the edit function though. What are the possibilities?

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } from '@wordpress/edit-post';
import { Component } from '@wordpress/element';

const renderMap = function() {
    let googleMap = document.getElementById('google-map')
    let map
  map = new google.maps.Map(googleMap, {
    center: { lat: 37.79406, lng: -122.4002 },
    zoom: 14,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
  })
}

registerBlockType( 'splash-blocks/google-maps', { 
    title: __('Google maps locations', 'google-maps'),
    icon: 'megaphone',
    category: 'common',
    keyword: [
        __( 'Display Google maps locations' ),
    ],
    atrributes: {
        markers: {
            type: 'object'
        },
    address: {
        type: 'string',
        default: 'xxxxxxxxx',
        }, 
        api_key: {
        type: 'string',
        default: 'xxxxxxxxx',
        }
    },
    edit: class extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props)
      }

     componentDidMount() {
            renderMap()
        }

        render() {
            const { attributes, setAttributes } = this.props

            return ( 
                <div id='google-map'>
                </div>
            )
        }
    },
    save: props => {
        const {
      className,
      attributes: { mapHTML }
    } = props;
renderMap()
        return (
            <div id='google-map'>
            </div>
        )
    }
})
```

Comment: ***no, you don't***, `save` is used to figure out what HTML to put in the database. Your `save` component does not run on the frontend. So it does not make sense for there to be interactive components or stateful components in the save function. If you want to use javascript in your block on the frontend, then that has nothing to do with the `save` or `edit` components. You need to enqueue a separate frontend JS asset that takes the HTML you saved and does things

Comment: Ok, got it. So how would I then pass my Block attributes to an external googlemaps enqueued script? I think I'd be using render_callback to grab the attributes and return them in a PHP function. Then use localized_script to pass them to the google maps external script.